# How to Sum per category

Tags: excel

Is there a function in Excel that does SUM the Amount's of Type?

Result E2 = SUM all Amount of Type = 'A'.

E2 = 695,
E3 = 40,
E4 = 73

[image]

Comment: `SUMIF` or `SUMIFS` or else just a pivot table

Comment: Thanks for the downvote and not leaving any remarks on what is wrong with the question.

Comment: I would guess the downvoter's rationale was because you did demonstrate in any way that you had tried to solve your problem yourself. You really should post your attempt with a question. this one was pretty easy to google...

Comment: Next time I'll try to describe the process of finding a solution by logging my Google attempts and note my hours spend fidgeting with Excel's unfathomable logic if that'll prove my worthiness of asking or even daring to ask a question. Though I would appreciate some feedback (like yours) when someone down-votes is all. Thanks though.

Comment: If I literally google your title here plus your tag, google points you to SUMIF without you even to have to click a link https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sum+per+category+excel&rlz=1C1GGRV_enGB767GB767&oq=sum+per+category+excel&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i60l3j0l2.2909j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 so it's really quite understandable in this instance that someone would have expected some effort to be shown. But yeah, downvoting without commenting is pointless.

Comment: I knew the question wasn't a hard one. I did actually tried sumif before asking the question but couldn't get it to work because I suck at Excel. Out of frustration with Excel I put the question here and knew someone would help me get in the right direction. So I got what I came for.

Comment: Then in future, if you don't want downvotes, mention that you tried and failed to use `SUMIF`. At least you got an answer and not 5 close votes.

Comment: See, happens to us all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51538267/calling-python-files-from-airflow-using-absolute-path-references

Comment: haha figures :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `E2`, write

```
=SUMIFS(A:A,B:B,D2)
```